# Error in sliding up animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have my main activity in which on double click i need to slide up my button.
I am able to slide up the button but before it slide up from bottom, for a fraction of second it blinks.

```
 @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Log.d("year", "onDoubleTap: ");
            rl.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
            rl.startAnimation(slideUp);
            rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

i have initialy made it gone

```
     rl = findViewById(R.id.rl_test);
     rl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

this is my slide up xml

when i double tap on the screen the button should slideup from the bottom

Comment: Check if you have a 'animateLayoutChanges=true' in your layout xml. If you do, remove it. It creates animations based on element visibility...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I this this xml would be useful

Slide up

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="300"
android:fromYDelta="50%p"
android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

Slide Down

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="100%" />
```

Good luck